# Create PDF that Android devices could read

Tags: java, android, pdf

I use Apache PDFBox library to create pdf-files. It creates files with the XFA structure. Applications on PC, Mac or Linux can read these files without any problems. But Android devices cannot do it. I see the following error message in the pdf-file: 
*"Please wait... If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document"*.
I am trying to find a solution to create pdf files that could be read by Android devices. I cannot find any information how to do it.
Did anyone do something like that?

Comment: I always use iText. Never tried PDFBox.

Comment: rendering of XFA isn't supported by PDFBox.

Comment: A PDF is a PDF, but saying that "Android devices" can't read them is a bit generalizing. Surely there are lots of different PDF readers for Android? And do they *all* fail on your PDFs?

Comment: Using PDF with XFA means restricting oneself to a very few PDF viewers (are there any non-Adobe ones?) on a few platforms  (you named three, probably there aren't more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate a non-XFA PDF you'll probably have more luck with it. The XFA spec is large, complicated and not well supported. Adobe Reader supports it but not many other readers (on Android or on desktop).

Comment: I have a pdf file with xfa-structure and I cannot change it. So i am looking for a solution to convert this xfa into Acroform and create pdf file with AcroForm structure. It should allow to solve the issue with reading on android devises.